# class method with unlimited parameters

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code:

```
$array = array('foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bis', 'ter')
Arrays::without($array, 'foo', 'bis') // Returns array('bar', 'ter')
```

As you can see, the second and third parameter to calling the `Arrays::without` function. you can pass as many parameters as you want, such as:

```
Arrays::without($array, 'foo', 'bis','athirdparam','afourthparam') // Returns array('bar', 'ter')
```

Im trying to encapsulate this into a static method inside a class i have:

```
public static function without($arr,$p)
{
    return Arrays::without($arr,$p);
}
```

What i need to know is if there is a way i can pass unlimited arguments to this method `without` and use them inside my funciton call to `Arrays::without`

Answer (score 2):

You can call:

```
Arrays::without($arr, ...$p);
```

Where `$p` is an array or write your method like that:

```
public static function without($arr,$p)
{
    return Arrays::without($arr, ...$p);
}
```

But it's quite unnecessary.

Check splat operator: http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat

Answer (score 0):

Either use [func_get_args()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) inside the function, or `public static function without(...$args)` for the function signature.... it's all described [here in the PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)